# Proving the sifting property of the Dirac delta

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

How to prove the following property of the [Dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)?

$$ f(x)= \int_0^1 f(a) \delta (x-a)da $$

for $ 0 < x < 1 $

Comment: Don't you mean $f(a)$?

Comment: How are you defining Dirac Delta?

Comment: I think you mean for the $f(x)$ inside the integral to be $f(a)$, otherwise what you have written follows from $\int f(x)dx=1$

Comment: I couldn't help but make that small edit, in line with comments, that you surely do not want the "f" inside the integral to be independent of the variable of integration, etc. My own preference might have been to reverse the roles of 'a' and 'x', but that doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes I  see it is corrected now

Comment: Tomer, it really is important that you show what definition you're using. Some people take $\delta$ to be the functional that satisfies this property, so you need to show what definition you are using so they can help go from A to B...

Comment: That's only valid if $0<x<1.$

Comment: Made the edits - the definition is from Wikipedia and yes it is valid only for  0<x<1

Answer (score 0):

In general, the composition of a distribution with a nice function is defined so that the change of variable formula holds. In particular, the distribution $\delta(x-a)$ verifies by definition
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \varphi(a)\,\delta(x-a)\,\mathrm d a = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \varphi(x-y)\,\delta(y)\,\mathrm d y = \varphi(x-0) = \varphi(x)
$$
for any function $\varphi$ continuous at $x$. In your case, to take care of the boundaries, you can use the above property with $\varphi = \mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}\, f$ where $\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}$ is the indicator function of the set $[0,1]$ and get
$$
\int_{0}^1 f(a)\,\delta(x-a)\,\mathrm d a = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(a)\, f(a)\,\delta(x-a)\,\mathrm d a = \mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(x)\, f(x)
$$
if $x≠0$ and $x≠1$. In particular, if $x\in(0,1)$
$$
\int_{0}^1 f(a)\,\delta(x-a)\,\mathrm d a = f(x).
$$